# How to create a debian 3.x kernel rootfs on a 2.x host

Tags: debian, kernel, embedded

I'm trying to build a rootfs for an embedded A10 board.  This will be matched up against 3.0.62+ modules and a corresponding vmlinux image.

I've been trying for a few days to get a rootfs set up for a 3.x kernel using sid.

Attempting to install using debootstrap, ie:

```
sudo debootstrap --foreign --verbose --arch=armel --include=vim-nox,openssh-server,ntupdate,less --exclude=nano sid . http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian
```

is just giving me a build which expects the same kernel version as the host system.

So, for example, when I `sudo chroot` into the new rootfs, I get:

```
root@njord:/lib/modules# depmod
ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64: No such file or directory
```

which is searching for modules corresponding to the host system, not the kernel image / modules installed.

I feel like I must be missing something very obvious here.  Is there some flag I can set (either in the rootfs itself, or in the debootstrap phase) which sets the target kernel version to one that is different from the host?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish by running `depmod` inside the chroot? If you don't specify a version, then yes, it will use the version of the running kernel as documented in `man depmod`:

```
       depmod [-b basedir] [-e] [-E Module.symvers] [-F System.map] [-n] [-v]
              [-A] [-P prefix] [-w] [version]

       depmod [-e] [-E Module.symvers] [-F System.map] [-m] [-n] [-v]
              [-P prefix] [-w] [version] [filename...]

[...]

       If a version is provided, then that kernel version's module directory
       is used rather than the current kernel version (as returned by uname
       -r).
```